# Streamlines not being displayed in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot streamlines following the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamline.html). My data is in the `meshgrid`-format as described there.

However, when I try to plot it using `streamline(x,y,vx,vy)` all I get is an empty figure ranging from 0 to 1. When I add starting points, it is still blank`streamline(x,y,vx,vy, 1:5,0*(1:5))`.

What am I missing to get the streamlines plotted?

Here is my data:

```
x =  [0         0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500,
      0         0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500,
      0         0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500,
      0         0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500,
      0         0.0125    0.0250    0.0375    0.0500];

y =  [0         0         0         0         0,
      0.0125    0.0125    0.0125    0.0125    0.0125,
      0.0250    0.0250    0.0250    0.0250    0.0250,
      0.0375    0.0375    0.0375    0.0375    0.0375,
      0.0500    0.0500    0.0500    0.0500    0.0500];

vx = [0.0009   -0.0019   -0.0058   -0.0040   -0.0028,
      0.0012    0.0159    0.1207    0.1465    0.0985,
      0.0007    0.0018   -0.0367    0.2432   -0.0053,
      0.0004    0.0920    0.1796    0.3807    0.0338,
     -0.0006    0.1708    0.1764    0.2567    0.1256];

vy = [0.0002    0.0000   -0.0001   -0.0001   -0.0001,
     -0.0003   -0.0156   -0.0076   -0.0251   -0.0433,
     -0.0008   -0.0113   -0.0218   -0.0519   -0.0720,
     -0.0006   -0.0091   -0.0326   -0.0778   -0.1087,
     -0.0003   -0.0026   -0.0025   -0.0416   -0.1048];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided range is not correct because you want to plot *x* in the range from *1* to *5* when your data contains values for *x* in the range from *0* to *0.5*.

If you set your starting points to something more reasonable, you will get the streamlines as expected. We can for example use *x = 0.015* and *y = 0.01 ... 0.05* as in the example below:

```
streamline(x,y,vx,vy, ones(1,5)*0.015, 0.01:0.01:0.05);
```

[image: result]

---

To get an impression on where you could set your starting points, you can use [`quiver`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html). Then you see arrows representing the velocity at the defined points in the dataset. Depending on that you can decide which starting points to use.

```
quiver(x,y,vx,vy);
```

[image: quiver-plot]